# Did older versions of Perl have different array indexing rules?

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm currently working on translating some Perl Code written in 1996/8 into Python.
I'm just wondering. Current Perl seems to have 0-based indexing for arrays (i.e. the first element would be:

```
Array1[0]
```

for example and the last element would be

```
Array1[$#Array1-1]
```

(I think... better at understanding Perl than writing it)
Was just wondering if in earlier versions they had the first as

```
Array1[1]
```

and the last as

```
Array1[$#Array1]
```

Was just wondering if this may have changed at some point in development?
This could be my own stupidity, in which case I've just got to work through my understanding of the program better, but if anyone could point me to which one it is, I would appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: If you showed the piece of the script that made you think arrays could be one-indexed, we might be able to explain it. (Of course, it would probably be best to post a new question for that.)

Comment: if you have stumbled upon negative indices, they are read from the end. So `$array[$#array] == $array[-1]`. Also `$#array` denotes the last index, if you want the size, you'll need `scalar @array`.

Answer (score 11):

Nope, first element is always `$Array1[0]` and last is `$Array1[$#Array1]` or `$Array1[-1]` or `$Array1[@Array1 -1]`

Exception for first element is only when changing default value of [`$[`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5b)

> This variable stores the index of the first element in an array, and of the first character in a substring. The default is 0, but you could theoretically set it to 1 to make Perl behave more like awk (or Fortran) when subscripting and when evaluating the index() and substr() functions.
>
> .. Mnemonic: [ begins subscripts.
> **Deprecated** in Perl v5.12.0.

Comment: `$[` was only officially deprecated in 5.12, but it was strongly discouraged long before that, and went through several changes to restrict it in between. (First, it was changed from a global to a lexical pragma, then it was limited to values zero or one.)

Comment: @MrJanx you can accept answer if it works for you by checking it on the left part of the answer.